# Truly portable (USB) install of Texlive?

Tags: installing

I always use LaTeX on different computers, so I hope to install a LaTeX system on a USB drive. I tried to install the LaTeX Portable on my USB drive, then I insert it into another computer, but I found it can't be used normally. Is there a way to make a flash drive USB LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, there is. Just run the installer with the `-portable` option: `install-tl -portable`

Comment: @AlexG I clicked the `install-tl-windows.bat` in USB drive, but it installed again. So installing USB LaTeX only download the files in USB. Am I right?

Comment: I can only speak for the `Linux` version of the installer. If you run the installer by click, you may need to set the portable option by setting the corresponding checkmark somewhere in the process and adjust the target parent directory `TEXDIR`.

Comment: @AlexG Okay, but I use Windows 11. Thanks for your idea for Linux.

Comment: I just tested the Windows installer on another computer. Within the installer GUI,  you need to open the "Advanced" menu, in order to set the "portable installation" option and to adjust `TEXDIR`, the installation root directory.

Comment: @AlexG I did as you said, so I installed LaTeX in my USB drive, but it can't be used in another computer.

Comment: @Y.zeng have you set the path on the second machine?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How to set the path on the second machine?

Comment: just  usual windows settings (as you must also have done on the first machine if works there?) all texlive does is  copy the files to a directory but in any operating system you need the folder with `pdflatex` to be in your path so when you type `pdflatex` it knows what program to run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I started the texworks in the USB drive, and ran it. It showed: Error launching Console Application PDFLaTeX .  How should I fix it?

Comment: You can set your system PATH environment using the windows control panel but I believe texworks has an option to set the path locally  in its configuraion menu but I do not have texworks so can not help more.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I set the path. Now the error is:`fmtutil [ERROR]: -user mode but path setup is -sys type` and `I can't find the format file pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: "On Windows, you can double-click tl-tray-menu at the root of the installation and create a temporary ‘tray menu’ oﬀering a choice of a few common tasks."
https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2

Comment: I can find `tray menu` and open it. How should I modify it to suit texworks?@hair-splitter

Comment: Choose the 'Editor' menu item

Comment: @hair-splitter 'Editor'-'Preference'-'typesetting` and what should I modify? I change the location of `pdflatex`

Comment: @Y. zeng No need to change anything. Just use it.

Comment: @hair-splitter but the error is `fmtutil [ERROR]: -user mode but path setup is -sys type` and `I can't find the format file pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: @Y. zeng Then the installation may be bad.

Comment: @hair-splitter Is there a way to repair it?

Comment: @Y. zeng Try tray menu / Package manager / Actions

Comment: @hair-splitter You are so excellent. It can be used in another computer now. May you teach me how to set `xelatex-biber-xelatex-xelatex` in texworks with one click?

Comment: @Y. zeng Set the `latexmk.exe` with `-xelatex` argument in TeXworks / Edit / Preferences / Typesetting

Comment: @hair-splitter It is too obvious to imagine. Could you send me a figure of that?